# What is the alternative for jquery each in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to remove jquery from my app.. But I want substitute for $.each in angularjs... 
How can I loop around dom elements ??
Here I have added my code.. I want to convert it into angularjs from jquery

```
app.directive('activeu', function($location) {
        return function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            var menuMain = $scope.$parent.menuMain;
            var fullpath = $location.path().split('/');
            var current = fullpath[2];

            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".nav li a").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).attr('href') ==  '#!/page/' + current) {
                        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                        $(this).closest('li.root-li').addClass('active');

                        if ($(this).closest('li.parent').length > 0) {
                            $(this).closest('li.parent').addClass('active');
                        }
                    }
                });

                $(".nav li a").on('click', function() {
                    current = $(this).attr('href');
                    $("#pages-menu .navigation li").each(function() {
                        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                            $(this).removeClass('active');
                        }
                    });

                    $(".nav li a").each(function() {
                        if ($(this).attr('href') ==  current) {
                            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                            $(this).closest('li.root-li').addClass('active');

                            if ($(this).closest('li.parent').length > 0) {
                                $(this).closest('li.parent').addClass('active');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            }, 500);
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
angular.forEach(angular.element("li a"), function(value, key){
     var a = angular.element(value);
     a.addClass('ss');
});
```

You can convert it into object and then, you can use it..

Answer (score 15):

you can use the loop statement [angular.forEach()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.forEach)

```
var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key){
  console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
```

Comment: its giving me like var htm = "<a href="#!/login">Login</a>".. I can access it like htm.href.. but instead if I want to access it like htm.attr('href'), how can i do it??

Comment: @amss I think you need to share some more details what kind of data you are trying to iterate and what is the desired output

Comment: I edited my question... I want to replace jquery each to angular.forEach

Comment: @amss since it is a directive and you are doing dom manipulation jQuery seems to be best fit here

Comment: @amss angular js also uses a trimmed version of jQuery if you do not include one yourself. Still if you do not want then you need to do raw dom manipulation